# php regex to get a string pattern

Tags: php, regex

I want to get all take profit value from a raw text.
however writing pattern is not same.

I get all values fine which i want except for 20/30/50. for that value i get only 20.

**I want whole word as 20/30/50**

```
$s = 'SS 1.0140 SL 1.0670 TP1 1.0870 TP 1 1.0870 TP 2 1.0870 Takeprofit1 1.0870 Take profit 1 1.0870 TP 1.0870 TP 20/30/50 TP-----1.0870 TP=1.0870 TP1=1.0870 TP Open';

$p = '#\b(TAKE ?PROFIT ?(?:[1-3]|\|TP|at)|TP ?(?:[1-3](?!\.\d))?)\b(.*?)\b(Open|(\d+(?:\.\d+)?))\b#i';

preg_match_all($p , $s , $m);
```

result of `$m[3]`:

```
Array
(

    [3] => Array
        (

            [0] => 1.0870
            [1] => 1.0870
            [2] => 1.0870
            [3] => 1.0870
            [4] => 1.0870
            [5] => 1.0870
            [6] => 20
            [7] => 1.0870
            [8] => 1.0870
            [9] => 1.0870
            [10] => Open
        )
)
```

Comment: _I want to get all take profit value from a raw text_ , so what are those profit values? Only numerical values? What are the different formats of numerical values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `(?:/\d+)*` to your third capture group.

https://regex101.com/r/hsQ0xD/1/

This makes the repeating non-capturing group (substring) "slash then one or more numbers" optional.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/IlTP9))

```
$s = 'SS 1.0140 SL 1.0670 TP1 1.0870 TP 1 1.0870 TP 2 1.0870 Takeprofit1 1.0870 Take profit 1 1.0870 TP 1.0870 TP 20/30/50 TP-----1.0870 TP=1.0870 TP1=1.0870 TP Open';

$p = '#\b(TAKE ?PROFIT ?(?:[1-3]|\|TP|at)|TP ?(?:[1-3](?!\.\d))?)\b(.*?)\b(Open|(\d+(?:\.\d+)?(?:/\d+)*))\b#i';

preg_match_all($p , $s , $m);

var_export($m[3]);
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => '1.0870',
  1 => '1.0870',
  2 => '1.0870',
  3 => '1.0870',
  4 => '1.0870',
  5 => '1.0870',
  6 => '20/30/50',
  7 => '1.0870',
  8 => '1.0870',
  9 => '1.0870',
  10 => 'Open',
)
```

Comment: Wow Thanks. appreciated!

Comment: With a better understanding of your data's variability and a battery of sample strings, I'd probably try to construct a comprehensive parsing pattern using `preg_match()` instead of `preg_match_all()`. The current technique will only become harder to extend and read as requirements and values change.